# python3 function read a file write a file default overwrite the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input, output

I want to create a function, read in a txt file, remove leading space and trailing space for each line, then write to a file, default to overwrite the file I read in, but with option to write to a new file.
Here is my code.

```
def cleanfile(inputfile, outputfile = inputfile):
    file1 = open(inputfile,'r')
    file2 = open(outputfile, 'w')
    lines = list(file1)
    newlines = map(lambda x: x.strip(), lines)
    newlines = list(newlines)
    for i in range(len(newlines)):
        file2.write(newlines[i] + '\n')
    file1.close()
    file2.close()    
cleanfile('hw.txt',)
cleanfile('hw.txt','hw_2.txt')
```

But it give me error. NameError: name 'inputfile' is not defined

How to solve this problem and achieve my goal please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standard convention in Python is to use `None` as a default and check for that.

```
def cleanfile(inputfile, outputfile = None):
    if outputfile is None:
        outputfile = inputfile
    file1 = open(inputfile,'r')
    file2 = open(outputfile, 'w')
    lines = list(file1)
    newlines = map(lambda x: x.strip(), lines)
    newlines = list(newlines)
    for i in range(len(newlines)):
        file2.write(newlines[i] + '\n')
    file1.close()
    file2.close()    
cleanfile('hw.txt',)
cleanfile('hw.txt','hw_2.txt')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't set outputfile=inputfile as a default parameter. This is a limitation of Python - 'inputfile' doesn't exist as a variable when the default parameter is specified.

You could use a sentinel value:

```
sentinel = object()
def func(argA, argB=sentinel):
    if argB is sentinel:
       argB = argA
    print (argA, argB)

func("bar")           # Prints 'bar bar'
func("bar", None)     # Prints 'bar None'
```

Comment: probably better to just default arg2 to None and check that instead of bothering with a custom sentinel object unless you need to handle user provided None different from default

Comment: No it isn't. `None` may be semantically meaningful at the level of the caller. (And if it's not, you're using nulls wrong.)

Comment: @user234461 sentinel is new to me, but this way works. Thanks.

Comment: there are plenty of cases (in the standard library even) where None is a perfectly acceptable default. See the code for [os.walk](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6370f345e1d5829e1fba59cd695c8b82c5a8c620/Lib/os.py#L278)

Comment: @avigil The context in `os.walk` is totally different: there, `onerror = None` really means that on an error, nothing should happen, so any sane caller passing a dynamically-generated `None` as `onerror` would not be surprised to find no action taken as a result. By contrast, stomping on the input file is not sensible default behaviour when the output file has been computed to be `None`: it's naughty whereas performing the operation inline *when the programmer has specifically chosen not to include a second parameter* is perfectly sensible, and not surprising. $personal_insult

Comment: respectfully, many in the python community disagree with you @user234461 [here](http://graysonkoonce.com/always-use-none-for-default-args-in-python/), [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#what-you-should-do-instead), [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html#use-a-sentinel-value-to-denote-an-empty-list-or-dictionary), [here](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/). The reasoning behind this is that `None` is immutable, while your sentinel object is not.

Comment: example: in the code you provide, if you accidentally modify `sentinel` at any point after `func` is declared, your function is now broken in a way that will be hard to debug in any reasonably complicated project. `func("bar"); sentinel=object(); func("bar");`

Comment: @avigil I tend to solve that problem by not randomly mashing the keyboard without thinking. Besides, if Python had `const` none of this would be an issue.

Comment: its not an issue- use `None` like everyone else :) its not so bad, I promise